Does magnetized metal have greater potential enrgy?
My understanding is that it takes work to magnetize fermomagnetic metal.  Once magnetized it has the ability to do work which also results in loss of magnetization.  Doies this then imply permanent magnets have higher potential energy than their unmagnetized counterparts?  If so this seems strange as in my experience magnets turn so their poles align which seems to imply that aligned magnets are a lower energy state and counter-aligned which doesn't add up in my mind.

Yes, a magnetized object is higher in energy than the corresponding unmagnetized object because the magnetic field itself holds energy density proportional to the square of the magnetic field strength. So, in an unmagnetized object, where the macroscopic magnetic field is cancelled as far as possible (because of the random arrangement of the microscopic dipoles) there will be less energy than in a magnetized object.
In order to make the microscopic dipoles align to produce a macroscopic field, you need to be able to put like dipoles side-by-side like this:
+ + + + + + + + + +
| | | | | | | | | |
- - - - - - - - - -

Classical electromagnetism predicts that setting up this configuration requires work because we have like poles in proximity. In a paramagnetic material, such a configuration is not stable and will rapidly demagnetize and thus reach its lowest energy configuration. The net dipole moment at equilibrium will be zero unless there is an applied external magnetic field. Ferromagnetism is a quantum-mechnical phenomenon. An object with permanent magnetization is not in its lowest-energy state, but is metastable as long as it is sufficiently below its Curie temperature.

That's a great answer but I'm still not clear on how this fits with properties I observe of magnets at the macroscopic scale.  If you put a bunch of magnets randomly aligned on a table and shake it they will spontaneously align with eachother and come together.

@DerekSeabrooke Well, if they stick together instead of repelling, then it means their opposite poles are in contact. You can stick together two bar magnets end-to-end, but the more stable configuration is the one in which the magnets are side-by-side so that each pole is in contact with the opposite pole from the other magnet. That would mean their dipole moments point in opposite directions and cancel each other out.
